# URL pattern not being identified by Django

Tags: python, django

I followed a tutorial by a youtuber known as Mosh, I followed along with his Django tutorial but whenever I enter the URL pattern, it gives me error 404, page not found. This is a [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxVMC.png) of the explorer tab.

I only edited the *views.py*, *products.urls.py* and *pyshop.urls.py* files.

**views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to the new products page!")

def new(reqest):
    return HttpResponse("New Products")
```

**products.urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index),
    path("new", views.new)
]
```

**pyshop.urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("products/", include("products.urls"))
]
```

Comment: what is the path you tried and what is the error you got
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#debug

Comment: the path for what? it basically told me that the page couldn't be found.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot from your 404 page? Normally Django generate available URLs on 404 error page, if your debug is True (in settings.py)

Comment: You may not have added products to your `INSTALLED_APPS`!

Answer (score 0):

the way you have it should work if you have the url as

```
localhost:8000/products
#or
localhost:8000/products/new
```

Comment: do i type in local host as it is?

Comment: Yup! Your browser will take you to the correct place